# EVM Assembly tags

Tags: storage, solc, assembly, yellow-paper, compiler

Studying the [Solidity optimizer](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/miscellaneous.html), I found that the assembly code is divided into tags and the optimizer doesn't work between them:

> It splits the sequence of instructions into basic blocks at JUMPs and JUMPDESTs.

After reading all the documentation, what I can gather is that the tags are those blocks, but I can't get a clear idea on the following:

- Why the optimisation fails between tags only for storage and memory OP? - Is there some example of an operation optimisation between the tags?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you are so worried about the cost of instruction, why don't you write your contract directly on assembly. it is going to be the best way to optimize it

Comment: I never wrote that i'm worried about the cost of gas or that i have to write any contract, i'm just studying the optimizer behaviour.